# How to show data from material dropdownlist if you select the dropdownlist in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a dropdownlist and I want to show the data when you select the dropdownlist.

It works if I put the function in the ngOnInit:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(tap(console.log));
  }
```

But of Course I dont want to load the data if you didnt selected the dropdownlist. But if I make a function for it:

```
  getQrCodes() {
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(tap(console.log));
  }
```

And the template looks like this:

```
   <div
      class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
      <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValueOptie" >
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of returnQrCodes$ | async " value="option.value" >
          {{ option.qrCode }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </div>
```

And I select the dropdownlist nothing happens.

Thank you

I tried like this:

```
 <div
        class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
        <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "getQrCodes"  >
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of getOtherOptions(selectedSearch)" [value]="option.apiStatus" >
            {{ option.status }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </div>
```

I also tried like this:

```
  <div
        class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
        <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" (selectionChange)="getQrCodes($event.value)"  >
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of getOtherOptions(selectedSearch)" [value]="option.apiStatus" >
            {{ option.status }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </div>
```

I tried like this:

```
 <div class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
      <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValueOptie" (change)="getQrCodes()"  >
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of returnQrCodes$ | async " value="option.value" >
          {{ option.qrCode }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </div>
```

and this is the method:

```
 getQrCodes() {
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(tap(console.log));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're not calling the "getQrCodes()" function anywhere

Comment: yes, But how to parse the function in the template?

Comment: add (change)="getQrCodes()" in mat-select

Comment: like this:   <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValueOptie" (change)="getQrCodes()"  > Still  the list will not been updated

Comment: But I am using Angular 8

Comment: Dont understand it doesnt wokrs.

Comment: But if I do this: ngOnInit() {
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(tap(console.log));
  } it works.